# Microsoft Graph API SharePoint Files Search

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I try to search for files on `SharePoint Document Library` (e.g. the default 'root'). I created a few test-files by uploading them or create new Office files online and made some search-requests, e.g. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drive/root/search(q='{query}')` and until yesterday everything worked fine.

Now I started to edit files on `SharePoint` or created/uploaded new ones and with this edited or new files, I have the problem that I get no result when I search for them. "old" files, I created when I started I find although, as long as I don't edit them.

To get access I registered an App inside the AAD and gave it the needed permissions (

```
Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All, Files.Read.All, Files.ReadWrite.All
```

and a direct access to a specific file with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drive/items/{item-id}/` works also well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search will read data from indexed data, but crawling and re-indexing of a library need to take some time. So you the code return null for the new files:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drive/root/search(q='{query}')
```

The following code get the library data directly but not based on the indexed data, so it works well.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drive/items/{item-id}/
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem was that I didn't know the `item-id`, so I had do search for the Item. Meanwhile I found a other solution for my problem, because I know the path to the files, I use this code

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives/root:/{file-path}:/`

Is there a way to trigger or force the re-indexing?